# What is the optimal selling price of an item based on its historical price/volume data?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to figure out how to price items on a market that appears to move randomly but within certain bounds. For example, here is a brief look at the time series data:

```
DateTime               Price       Volume
2013-08-27 00:00:00 1.9299999476    4
2013-08-27 01:00:00 1.6849999428    2
2013-08-27 02:00:00 1.7024297714    2
2013-08-27 03:00:00 1.2264721394    2
2013-08-27 04:00:00 1.75            7
2013-08-27 05:00:00 1.5             2
2013-08-27 06:00:00 1.9299999476    3
2013-08-27 07:00:00 1.75            5
2013-08-27 08:00:00 1.7000000477    5
2013-08-27 09:00:00 1.8600000143    4
2013-08-27 10:00:00 1.8236290216    2
2013-08-27 11:00:00 1.8600000143    7
2013-08-27 12:00:00 1.8046891689    6
2013-08-27 13:00:00 1.9107458592    2
2013-08-27 14:00:00 1.9414916039    6
2013-08-27 15:00:00 1.9605424404    6
2013-08-27 16:00:00 1.8037977219    6
2013-08-27 17:00:00 1.871355176     4
2013-08-27 18:00:00 1.727257967     5
2013-08-27 19:00:00 1.6200000048    5
2013-08-27 20:00:00 1.8400000334    9
2013-08-27 21:00:00 1.8099999428    1
2013-08-27 22:00:00 1.8099999428    10
2013-08-27 23:00:00 1.7849999666    2
2013-08-28 00:00:00 1.8500000238    2
2013-08-28 01:00:00 1.8799999952    11
2013-08-28 03:00:00 1.9900000095    7
2013-08-28 04:00:00 1.8511325121    3
2013-08-28 05:00:00 1.8049999476    6
2013-08-28 06:00:00 1.8419520855    4
2013-08-28 08:00:00 1.7999999523    1
2013-08-28 09:00:00 1.9550000429    8
2013-08-28 10:00:00 1.9500000477    5
2013-08-28 11:00:00 1.9510477781    4
2013-08-28 12:00:00 1.9403985739    2
2013-08-28 13:00:00 1.75            3
2013-08-28 14:00:00 1.8400759697    6
```

So lets say I purchase one of these items at 1.50. The question is: at what selling price will I be able to maximize profit?

Also, how can I account for any cyclical price movement?

(as a side note, I am somewhat familiar with R and Rapidminer)

Comment: I thinks this is more suitable for http://quant.stackexchange.com/. You could model the series with some sort of autoregressive model, but I doubt the out of sample prediction would be accurate. You can account for seasonality or cyclical movements by adding deterministic terms to the regression.

Answer (score 1):

I read your question in the following way. What is the relationship between price and volume? If I can predict volume based upon some regularity be it based upon the time segment, day-of-the-week, level-shifts, trends, trends in daily values  etc THEN how can I then predict price and based upon predicted price determine when to sell. This prediction of price should take into account not only the "proven" impact of volume but any cyclicality/structure that is extractable from the past price data. Pursuing this thread I built a model between Price and Volume just using the 34 data points that you delivered which could not employ any hour-of-the-day or day-of-the week effects due to  the small number of observations . If more observations were available then more structure might be detectable. This answer is then a prototype and suggestive of what a larger model might employ. THe graph of the actual/fit/forecast [image] with statistics [image]. The plot of the forecasts based upon the predicted volume and the impact of price and identified interventions [image] . The equation is presented here [image]. For the record I used AUTOBOX a piece of software that I have helped develop. If you have some programming time and some knowledge of forming causal models while incorporating unspecified Pulses/Level Shifts/Local Time Trends and any needed ARIMA structure, you might be able to duplicate these results. I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is helpful, but is there any open source solution I could use (preferably one that can be employed on Linux or OSX)?

Comment: There is no open source solution that I am aware of. AUTOBOX does market a Linux Version but it is far from free. At least now you have a clue as to how to proceed with your analysis.